# Need help understanding working of react build artifacts in Django project

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-templates

I have a Django backend in which I have pasted build directory of react project (after running `npm run build`). I see a bunch of web pages of react project opening when opened through code, i.e. `<Link className='dropdown-item' to='/customer/dashboard'>Dashboard</Link>` opens the component routed by `<Route path="/customer/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />` (i.e. Dashboard component launches). But if I update the URL to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/customer/dashboard` or even refresh the page with the aforementioned URL, I get 404 error.
I also have another problem where some of the pages don't even open through code. So I am wondering why this could be.

Following is the code snippets I have in **urls.py** (Django project)

```
path('api/token/refresh/', jwt_views.TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
path('', views.index, name = 'index'),
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache

index = never_cache(TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))
```

Comment: Nope not yet...

Answer (score 0):

You ought to prevent client side routes from reaching the server. Use [**`<HashRouter>`** <sup>[react router docs]</sup>](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/hash-router#hashrouter) to envelope all your routes.